# Update an array of objects using another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

i need to update the array of objects based on another array in ES6.
Example

```js
let a = [ 
  { id : 23, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 33, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 167, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 18, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 200, active :false, status:"" },
]
```

my second array which contain the objects

```js
let marked = [167,33,23];
```

expected results as below

```js
let a = [ 
  { id : 23, active :true, status:"updated"},
  { id : 33, active :true, status:"updated" },
  { id : 167, active :true, status:"updated" },
  { id : 18, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 200, active :false, status:"" },
]
```

please let me know how to get as expected result. do we have any other methods in lodash for this.?

Comment: I assume you want {id:33, active:true} as well?

Comment: yes @BurakhanAksoy for 33, 23 and 167

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: there is typo that 18 has true isn't it?

Comment: yes @GiorgiMoniava 18 isn't true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just an extension of @Giorgi Moniava's answer since the question has been updated. I think you should mark his answer as the accepted one. Basically all you need to do is check if the value for `active` is true or false. If it's true, set the status to `updated` otherwise, set the status to an empty string.

```js
let a = [ 
  { id : 23, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 33, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 167, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 18, active :false, status:"" },
  { id : 200, active :false, status:"" },
]

let marked = [167,33,23];

let result = a.map(obj => {
    const isActive = marked.includes(obj.id);
    const status = isActive ? 'updated' : '';
    return {
      ...obj,
      active: isActive,
      status: status
    }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need lodash, you could do this:

```js
let a = [{
        id: 23,
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 33,
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 167,
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        active: false
    },
]

let marked = [167, 33, 23];

let result = a.map(x => ({
    ...x,
    active: marked.includes(x.id)
}))
console.log(result)
```

You can make this faster if you go over the `marked` array and store its elements in an object. Then during the `map` checking if element `x.id` is inside the object will be faster (vs checking inside array). But in practice in most of the cases you should not notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, use map function with includes function. Hope so this answer gives your actual result. if not then comment to me I'll give you another answer.

```
const found = a.map(function(mapData){
    (marked.includes(mapData.id)) ? mapData.active = true : '';
    return mapData;
})
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution since you're internally modifying the `mapData` object. Also, why the ternary expression? An `if` would do.